# How do I pass a polynomial variable into a matlab function?

Tags: matlab

I am just getting started with MATLAB and I have written a function to produce the binomial expansion of `(x-a)^n` when given `x`, `a` and `n`. As far as I can tell my code should work, but I do not seem to be using the function variables correctly.

```
function expand(a,n,x)
f = 0;
for k = 0:1:n
    f = f + nchoosek(n,k).*x.^(n-k).*(-a).^k;
end
end
```

I need to be able to call the function and have it output f as the expanded polynomial in `x`, for example calling `expand(1,3,x)` should return `x^3-3*x^2+3*x-1`, but instead, calling it gives this error:

> ```
> Unrecognized function or variable 'x'. It seems like it wants me to call the function with x being another number but I in fact need it to be able to be any letter to be used as the variable in the polynomial.
> ```

I know in Maple I would specify the variable type in the function to be `x::name` so I'm assuming there's something similar in MATLAB that I don't yet know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pass `x` as a symbolic variable. It sounds like you are trying to call the function without even defining `x`. Additionally, `expand` is a Matlab builtin function so it's best not use that as a function name.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? Do I need to define x = sym('x') outside of the function and then call it with expand(a,n,x)? Also thank you for your tip about the inbuilt function, I will change that now.

Comment: Yep, or even just `sym x`

Comment: What is your end goal? If it's to *see* the polynomial expansion then this can be a string output without any symbolic toolbox dependency, if it's to *evaluate* it then this can be constructed with an anonymous function, but you won't see the expansion... So when you say "should return `x^3-3*x^2+3*x-1`", what sort of variable is that returned expression?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

- Create `x` as a symbolic variable. For example, `syms x; expand(a,n,x)`. This gives you the power of using the symbolic toolbox features like `simplify()`, but comes with a bit of a performance penalty. You should avoid using the symbolic toolbox in intensive calculations.
- Return an anonymous function, `f=@(X)sum(arrayfun(@(k)nchoosek....,1:n)`. This has better performance and does not require `double(subs(...))` when you want an actual numeric value, but may be too difficult to implement for a beginner.

Comment: I feel like this is a bit of a rip off of the question comments, without actually providing a full answer. This is because **1.** You have barely expanded on the comments to show how the two options could be used, and **2.** The question doesn't have a clear goal and requires editing, something you should usually wait for to help provide a better answer.